# Multiple Windows in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to have more than one window (for the same project) in PhpStorm ? If yes, how ?

Comment: No, one frame per project. Why would you need multiple windows for the same project? Note that you can drag editor tab outside of the main window to create another window for the editor.

Comment: *Technically* it is possible .. but that would be 2 **different** projects but with the same content (which means each of them must be **configured separately**). But the Question remains -- why do you need it in first place?

Comment: @CrazyCoder good point ... that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @LazyOne let's say something like "multiple screens" ? ;)

Comment: @AsTeR In this case you already have your answer

Comment: Separate editor window does not support full-screen like the main window making it less than perfect for multiscreen setups.

Comment: I'm looking for this feature because I'm needing to deal with two different tasks, on two sets of files, across the day. Would be much easier if I could have those two sets of tabs together without closing and reopening every time I have to switch back and forth.

Comment: @igorsantos07 you can have multiple windows as CrazyCoder mentions

Comment: That's not exactly multi windows, it's a detached tab. You still can't open tool windows in the "child one", unless you detach from the other and alter your workspace. - tool windows seem unique. The menu isn't there either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PhpStorm supports only one frame per project.

Note that you can drag editor tab outside of the main window to create another window for the editor. Tool window panels can be also detached and moved to to the second display if you so desire.

Comment: If you want the same document opened in two windows: right-click on the document tab and choose split vertically then drag the new tab out of the main window.

Comment: So you cannot view the same project in two different workspaces?
Seems like a major limitation!

Answer (score 10):

You can choose `Split Horizontally` or `Split Vertically` from `Windows` menu!

As they are so useful, you can put two shortcuts to use them easier. I put *option* + *1* for splitting vertically and *option* + *shift* + *1* for splitting horizontally.

**Update**
In 2017 versions, The `Split Horizontally` and `Split Vertically` options are located into `Windows` > `Editor Tabs`

Answer (score 1):

I was going to add this as a comment, on Nima Ghaedsharafi's post.  The path to '''Split Horizontally''' and '''Split Vertically''' looks to be '''Window > Editor Tabs > Split ...''' in Version. 2017.1.4

Answer (score 1):

Note for those trying to add a key shortcut for the Split Horizontally or Split Vertically buttons:

As of 2017.3.4, you can add the shortcut by going to Settings -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Window -> Editor Tabs -> Split Vertically/Horizontally.

This still applies as of version 2019.2

Answer (score 0):

You can [split the editor window](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html) *but I'm not sure if that's what you were asking*.